# Function of a C++ DLL does not output text in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll

I am trying to output text from a C++ function to a textbox in WPF, but when I click the button it outputs nothing.
In the C# Console it worked.

Here the code from the C# console:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {
        const string dllfile = "C:\\...";
        [DllImport(dllfile, EntryPoint = "main", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern string text_output();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            text_output();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the code from the C++ DLL:

```
using namespace std;


void text_output();
void text_output()
{
    cout << "something" << endl;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int main()
{
    text_output();
    return 0;
}
```

Here the code from the C# WPF page:

```
namespace application
{
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        const string dllfile = "C:\\...";
        [DllImport(dllfile, EntryPoint = "main", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern string text_output();
        
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtBox.Text += text_output();
        }
        
    }
}
```

What do I have to do so that the text from the `text_output()` function is output to the textbox when I click the button?

Comment: `cout << "something" << endl;` writes to the console. That's all it does. `void text_output()` returns `void`, also known as nothing, so `private static extern string text_output();` is a lie and that lie makes `txtBox.Text += text_output();` meaningless.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes

Comment: Shouldn't the function be `extern "C" void text_output();`, otherwise the name will be C++ mangled.

Comment: To clarify: There is a mismatch between what the C++ code provides and what the C# code expects, and the trivial fix of making the C++ code return `string` won't help because a C++ `string` and a C# `string` are not compatible in spite of the name. I don't know C# well enough to offer help solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows (which `WPF` implies you are using), the `BSTR` can be created from standard wide-string, and you can try `C++` code like:

```cpp
#include <windows.h> // For BSTR from "wtypes.h" header.

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR text_output()
{
    return ::SysAllocString(L"something");
}

// ...
```

Then wrap into `string` with `MarshalAs` in your `C#` declaration, like:

```
const string dllfile = "C:\\...";
[DllImport(dllfile, EntryPoint = "main", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
private static extern string text_output();
```

---

P.S. You may need to convert `char *` to Wide-String, something like:

```cpp
BSTR StrToBSTR(const char *value) {
    int valueLength = lstrlenA(value);
    if (valueLength > 0) {
        int resultLength = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, value, valueLength, NULL, 0);
        if (resultLength > 0) {
            BSTR result = ::SysAllocStringLen(0, resultLength);
            ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, value, valueLength, result, resultLength);
            return result;
        }
    } 
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The returned string should be passed to *SysFreeString* when no longer required.

Comment: Only if called in `C++` directly, but NOT if called from `C#`, there P/invoke marshaller is going to try to release the memory for the `string` with `CoTaskMemFree(...)` method.